# Judder on div text on page load on Heroku but works fine in development environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working on a website for a client who has become a fairly close friend, so I am trying to get everything perfect for him (he'd probably overlook this issue but that's not the kind of work I want to be doing). The site is working fine in the development environment but in (pre-)production on Heroku there is a very disconcerting judder on pageload (particularly when clicking the navigation link at the top of the page) which you can see by visiting the Heroku URL:

https://gentle-headland-62741.herokuapp.com/products

There are a fair few different SCSS, HTML and JS files being loaded so it wouldn't make sense to reproduce them all here, but here are what seem to be the most likely sections of code to track down the culprits:

**products.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";

.row {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.accordian {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.accordian > div {
  background-color: #eaeaea !important;
  overflow: scroll !important;
}

.ui-state-focus { 
  outline: none;
}

.servicestext {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}

.paper-image {
  padding: 15px;
}

.text-box {
  background: #efefef;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;
}
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, "Products and Solutions") %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'products' %>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="image-box image-left-box col-md-5"><%= image_tag("cogs-binary-shiny.jpg", class: "image", id: "paper-image") %></div>
        <div class="synopsis-text text-box col-md-6"><h1>Products and Solutions</h1>
          <p class="product-text">Simutronix offers multiple profit optimisations solutions, tailored
          to suit the needs of any business, large or small. From face to face consultancy,
          to bespoke optimisation solutions, to the off the shelf <em>SimutronX</em>, we have
          something to suit every business model.
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" text-box col-sm-5" id="services_accordian">
        <h2>Profit Optimisation; Cost Reduction; Services Streamlining</h2>
        <div class="accordion">
          <h3>Profit Optimisation</h3>
          <div class="accordian-title">
            <p>We can take your business and turn it from
            a loss making venture into a formula for success.
            We use cutting edge mathematical techniques
            derived from derivations of historical data
            processing methodologies created by some
            of the greatest minds in history.</p>
          </div>
          <h3>Cost Reduction</h3>
          <div class="accordian-title">
            <p>We can make sure every part of your
            business works properly with every other 
            part. From traditional, albeit two-dimensional, 
            sales and marketing synergies through 
            to a complete and holistic approach,
            seeing your entire company as a living,
            breathing organism in its own right. A
            moving, changing, <em>dynamic</em> body
            of ever differing elements that is far, 
            far more than the sum of its parts,
            and yet is always an expression of all 
            of its constituent elements.
           </p>
          </div>
          <h3>Services Streamlining</h3>
          <div class="accordian-title">
            <p>When your sales team are producing works of fantasy,
            often through no fault of their own, it can
            be difficult to know what specification to manufacture to.
            Of course, no-one entirely understands what the market will do
            next but you know that what you want, what your company
            absolutely needs is to be flexible while retaining its
            core ethos, its belief system and the markets that
            made it successful in the first place.</p>
            <p>That success may have come easier to start with,
            but if you're honest with yourself, you've found things
            becoming more difficult, more complex. You're sure
            you could break through to the next level, if only
            you could reliably model what's actually happening
            within your company and outside, in the wider world
            where you products, your services are being sold.
            And that's why sometimes you need those old-fashioned
            things, like maths, science, models and formulae,
            to get control back, and to really push things
            forward in exactly the way you have <em>always</em>
            been capable of.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-box image-right-box col-sm-6"><%= image_tag("new-small-statue.jpg", class: "image", id: "statue-image") %></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="image-box image-left-box col-md-5"><%= image_tag("pen-hand-small.jpg", class: "image", id: "pen-image") %></div>
      <div class="copytext text-box col-md-6">
        <h2>Margin Improvement</h2>
        <p><em>Margin improvement is about making more profit by improving what you already do.</em> Cost engineering, better and sharper buying, pricing appropriately, discounting less and investing in equipment
        which will do more, quicker and with less man-hours expended. In conjunction with optimisation, the two can result in truly 
        startling profit improvements.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**custom.js (uses jQuery accordion as a called library)**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  $(".accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });

  $(".ui-accordion-header").css("background","grey");
  $(".ui-accordion-header").css("focus","grey");
  $(".ui-accordion-header").css("border","#acb8a9");

});
```

If anyone could help me with this I would be *extremely grateful* as I really want to get the website as close to perfect as possible for the client, who has been friendly, understanding, and just in general a joy to work for.

The judder can be seen in this gif:

[image: Judder gif]

The judder also appears present in Firefox, but is much less noticeable.

Comment: FWIW I did not see the judder. What browser are you using, and can you create a GIF of the error?

Comment: I'm using Chrome on Windows 10. I'll test with another browser and see if I can create a gif for you.

Comment: Added gif and result of Firefox testing to question.